# unir 2 consutas a traves de union y dejar el resultado en una tabla temporal

Tags: sql

tengo 2 consultas a tablas diferentes, que tienen la misma estructura, pero diferentes registros. Ambos selects los puedo unir con UNION, y quiero que este resultado, se grabe en una tabla temporal.

Los querys son simples

```
Select * from tabla A
union
Select * from tabla B
```

lo que necesito (y no me resulta) es que el resultado de este Union, quede en una tabla temporal

intente esto, pero no me funciona

```
Select * from tabla A
union
Select * from tabla B
Into #tablaTemP
```

pls ayuda. gracias

Comment: Insert into tabla (todo el select)

Comment: @ManucoBianco eso sería para insertar datos en una tabla que ya existe. Para insertar el resultado en una nueva tabla, se debe usar `SELECT * INTO dbo.Tabla FROM …..`

Comment: Buena aclaración. Gracias @Lamak

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta estimados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente estás usando en un lado equivocado la sentencia `INTO Tabla`; debe ir inmediatamente antes del primer `FROM`:

```
Select * 
Into #tablaTemP
from tabla A

union

Select * 
from tabla B;
```

Comment: excelente respuesta,muchas gracias!!

Comment: Y como haría en el caso de querer mostrar resultados de 2 tablas, por ejemplo tengo "ingresos y egresos", ambas tablas tienen los mismos campos, con los mismos nombres y orden, comparten un campo llamado tabla la cual es "I o E" segun Ingresos y Egresos, necesito listar los resultados de ambas tablas pero que se muestre el campo tabla segun corresponda, intenté con UNION pero lo que hace es unirlos laterales, necesito que los resultados se unan por filas y no por columnas.